# Extracting all rows and columns (with their rowspans and colspans) of an HTML table with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

I'm trying to extract all the values in the cells of an HTML table with XQuery. The query I'm using, which you can find below, gives the following result

```
Warning on line 11 column 22 of queryExtractTable.xq:
  The child axis starting at an attribute node node will never select anything
Warning on line 11 column 63 of queryExtractTable.xq:
  The child axis starting at an attribute node node will never select anything
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>hello colspan rowspan
```

I don't understand why "The child axis starting at an attribute node node will never select anything".

I'm using Saxon.

Here is the query

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";


declare function local:analyzeTable(
$table as element(table))
{
    for $r in $table//tr
        return
            for $c in $r//td
                    return (normalize-space($c), string("colspan"),
$c/@colspan//text() , string("rowspan"), $c/@rowspan//text() )

};


for $t in //table
    return
        local:analyzeTable($t)
```

The table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is raised by expressions like the following:

```
$c/@colspan//text()
```

`@colspan` is an attribute node, and attribute nodes do not have any child nodes. So when you ask for an attribute's descendant `text()` nodes, Saxon raises a warning.

To access the string value of these attributes, you can change these expressions to:

```
string($c/@colspan)
```

I see you're already familiar with the `string()` function, e.g., `string("colspan")`; please note though that the `string()` function here is extraneous, and `"colspan"` is sufficient to construct a literal string.

For more on `text()` versus `string()` or `data()`, see https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell.